# Snapshot on, still deadlocks in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I enabled snapshots in my SQL Server 2016 database, 16 Core CPU, 43 GB memory.

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase
SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON

ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase
SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
```

After that, I got deadlock on my database

> Transaction (Process ID 69) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

I checked the error line number -Delete operation on table

Tables has 7882884 rows with two columns.

Also my stored procedure is running with a begin / end trans block where my table is written

Regards,
Manish

Comment: My Delete operation is delete from tablename where id=@id

Comment: error log-Error Number-1205, ErrorSeverity-13- Error State-78, Maxdop=10,cost threshold for parallelism=10 i have total 16 Cpu and SQL Server Memoery-43GB

Comment: `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` can help avoid deadlocks when readers block writers and visa-versa. However, it will not avoid deadlocks between writers. I suggest query and index tuning to ensure only data needed by the delete query is touched. Check the system_health Extended Event session to get the XML deadlock graph event, which will have details of the queries involved.